# Return result even if not within the joint tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Can anyone please help me with this task? Let's say I have 2 tables:

_Table 1 "Publisher": ASIN, Price, publisher_ID

_Table 2 "Violations": ASIN, publisher_ID, Previous_Violations (Y/N), ID

Now I have this

```
    SET @PUB = "

    'A','B','C','D',

    " 
    SELECT p.publisher_ID, count(distinct v.id) as "Number of Violations"
    FROM Publisher p
    LEFT JOIN Violations v
    ON p.publisher_ID = v.publisher_ID
    and p.Previous_Violations = 'Y'
    
    WHERE 
    p.publisher_ID IN (",@PUB,")
    GROUP BY p.publisher_ID
```

I want to see the history violations of all publishers in the @PUB list. So there will be 4 cases:

1. All publishers in @PUB exist both tables
2. There are publishers in @PUB that exist in table 1, but not 2.
3. There are publishers in @PUB that exist in table 2, but not 1.
4. There are publishers in @PUB that don't exist in any of the 2 tables.

To clarify, let's say pubs A & B exist in both tables, C exists in table 1 (not 2), D exists in table 2 (but not 1), and E doesn't exist in either.

Right now my query above only gives (due to left join)

> A   3
>
> B   2
>
> C   4

But I'd like it to show:

> A   3
>
> B   2
>
> C   4
>
> D   6
>
> E   Null

Comment: can you post your actual data for us to understand why E and D are not showing up

Comment: You will NEVER get E in your select if the record doesn't exist in either of the tables you are selecting from. That's your first problem to solve.

Comment: Use "FULL OUTER JOIN" instead of left join to get D. As far as getting E, you may need to load all the values in @PUB as a temp table and do "full outer join" on all these three tables.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Sorry I can't do that since the data contains personal information. But what I can say is our DB's sometimes messed up so

1). D is not showing up because we took action on some books (table 2) before the publisher and the ASIN's information were uploaded (table 1)

2) E is not showing up because the information was not uploaded (table 1) and there has been no violation (table 2)

But pub D and E do exist indeed

Comment: dilsingi I don't think MySQL allows Full Outer Join. Also, I'm thinking about creating a table with 1 column and fill in the @PUB. However, I don't know how and don't know how to join the rest to make sure "E" will show as wanted

Comment: i think you are missing a piece of info here... when you say E does not exists in both tables so question, where is the table that holds the E master data

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a large list you can try the following, you may be able to create a procedure that generates the query for you

```
(
    SELECT p.publisher_ID, sum(IF(v.Previous_Violations = 'Y', 1, 0)) AS "Number of Violations"
    FROM (SELECT 'A' AS publisher_ID) AS p LEFT JOIN Violations v USING(publisher_ID) 
    GROUP BY p.publisher_ID
)
UNION
(
     SELECT p.publisher_ID, sum(IF(v.Previous_Violations = 'Y', 1, 0)) AS "Number of Violations"
    FROM (SELECT 'B' AS publisher_ID) AS p LEFT JOIN Violations v USING(publisher_ID) 
    GROUP BY p.publisher_ID)
UNION
(
     SELECT p.publisher_ID, sum(IF(v.Previous_Violations = 'Y', 1, 0)) AS "Number of Violations"
    FROM (SELECT 'C' AS publisher_ID) AS p LEFT JOIN Violations v USING(publisher_ID) 
    GROUP BY p.publisher_ID)
UNION
(
     SELECT p.publisher_ID, sum(IF(v.Previous_Violations = 'Y', 1, 0)) AS "Number of Violations"
    FROM (SELECT 'D' AS publisher_ID) AS p LEFT JOIN Violations v USING(publisher_ID) 
    GROUP BY p.publisher_ID
)
UNION
(
     SELECT p.publisher_ID, sum(IF(v.Previous_Violations = 'Y', 1, 0)) AS "Number of Violations"
    FROM (SELECT 'E' AS publisher_ID) AS p LEFT JOIN Violations v USING(publisher_ID) 
    GROUP BY p.publisher_ID
)
```

Comment: Hello

Thanks a lot for this but this won't work because sometimes we have to deal with 40-50 publishers